# Drawing from lot of contexts to main contexts

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have lots of CGContextRef(for sake say 4). I want to get the data from those context and update one global context such that all context's data should be updated at appropriate location on scree and I have to keep the global(main) context updated with respect to updates in other context.

How can I achieve this and what could be the best way to do this?

Thanks in Advance. I really appreciate for your time.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you provide a more concrete example, with code if possible?

Comment: I dont have a code for now.. but I will try to explain more. I have lot of sources/threads from where data that needs to be displayed arrives. They all are handled in different contexts as they all have to be rendered on screen in different locations based on bounds information. For rendering data on main screen I have one context (which I call global). Now this global context needs to be updated. based on update on other contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other contexts you have, (apart from main context) mak sure those context are Bitmap Context. Then you can create a bitmap out of them and put that bitmap over main context.